# Should we alias [dotnetfiddle] to [.net-fiddle], or keep a duet of .net fiddle tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

We have the following two tags:

- [.net-fiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-fiddle) 10 questions, created Nov 10 '14:

  > [.NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net) is an online tool inspired by [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). It enables .NET developers to test simple code or try out samples from other developers, without having to start up Visual Studio.
- [dotnetfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotnetfiddle) 4 questions, created Jan 27, no guidance.

I've confirmed that all the questions in the second tag ask questions related to  https://dotnetfiddle.net, so can we alias it to the first?

Or shall we keep the current duet of fiddles?

Nobody has the prerequisite 5 rep to propose a synonym for either so moderator help would be required.

(The [.net-fiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-fiddle) tag help me to find [Problem with DotNetFiddle and Console.ReadLine that causes a Re-run when pressing ENTER key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65918816/3744182) and thereby close [Why does my random number generated keep changing in .NET Fiddle / dotnetfiddle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69518706/3744182) and [using .Net fiddle on a chromebook, tried to make a guessing game. the hints (higher or lower) arent working and the target number seems to change](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69997120/3744182) as duplicates, so for me, at least, the tag was useful.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree; seems clear that we should synonymize [dotnetfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotnetfiddle) to [.net-fiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-fiddle) here; the name of the actual service is ".NET Fiddle", it has a tag description, has twice as many questions, and it has existed for many more years.

The website is probably just named "dotnetfiddle" because you can't put a period in a domain name... periods are used to separate domains from subdomains (thanks, Microsoft for that whole .NET naming thing...). Might have been the spelled-out version also because for a while people were referring to it as "dotnet" while it .NET Core was still being previewed.